# Assigning a Unicode character with a size of 4 bytes to a char

Tags: java, unicode

I was trying to assign the Unicode character `0x10FFFF` to a `char`, but it failed with an error:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
         char a = 0x10FFFF;
         int b=a;
        System.out.println("b="+b+", but a="+a);
 }
```

Error:

```
HelloWorld.java:4: error: possible loss of precision
         char a=   0x10FFFF;
                   ^
  required: char
  found:    int
1 error
```

Now I know that the upper bound for  `char` is 65,535 as it uses a 16 bits for storage.

Does that mean that a `char` should never be used to represent Unicode characters? Should we always use an `int` when dealing with Unicode characters?
What good is the `char` type then?

Comment: When you add such a *code point* to a String it uses two `char` as one is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

> Does that mean that a char should never be used to represent Unicode characters?

No, Unicode characters in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) can still be represented by a `char`.

> Should we always use an int when dealing with Unicode characters?

No, use a `String` with [Surrogate Pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF). E.g. use `"\uD83C\uDF84"` to represent the Unicode character 'CHRISTMAS TREE' (U+1F384). There is a good Surrogate Pair calculator here: http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm

> What good is the char type then?

It can still represent any character that *is* in the Basic Multilingual Plane.

Comment: Why would you recommend using a `String` over an `int`?

Comment: @nwellnhof Because strings are meant to hold non-BMP characters, and a surrogate pair in a string can be printed with no trouble whatsoever. To print a non-BMP character represented by an `int`, you would have to do a lot of complex calculations.

Comment: Not necessarily complex calculations, since you can leverage the `isBmpCodePoint`, `highSurrogate`, and `lowSurrogate` methods of `Character`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Java, and the problem is addressed in the [Unicode section of the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html):

> *When the specification for the Java language was created, the Unicode standard was accepted and the char primitive was defined as a 16-bit data type, with characters in the hexadecimal range from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF.*
>
> *Because 16-bit encoding supports 216 (65,536) characters, which is insufficient to define all characters in use throughout the world, the Unicode standard was extended to 0x10FFFF, which supports over one million characters. The definition of a character in the Java programming language could not be changed from 16 bits to 32 bits without causing millions of Java applications to no longer run properly. To correct the definition, a scheme was developed to handle characters that could not be encoded in 16 bits.*
>
> *The characters with values that are outside of the 16-bit range, and within the range from 0x10000 to 0x10FFFF, are called supplementary characters and are defined as a pair of char values.*

Follow the link above for code examples and more information.

Comment: That documentation is just using a lot of fancy wording, but it boils down to the fact that Java was originally designed for UCS-2 (a 16bit encoding), which is why `char` is 16-bit, and when Unicode was extended to support codepoints past `0xFFFF` than UCS-2 was replaced with UTF-16 (another 16bit encoding), which Java now uses.  UTF-16 is backwards compatible with UCS-2 for `0x0000`-`0xFFFF`.